# Cannot get process/thread context, when switching to wow64 mode

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm using winDbg to debug some kernel/user-space issue in wow64 process running on windows 10 (version 1809).

when I switch to host (normal 64bit) mode everything work as expected and I can see the thread contents :

```
32.0: kd:x86> !wow64exts.sw
Switched to Host mode

32.0: kd> !thread
THREAD ffffaf043002e080  Cid 1fdc.1744  Teb: 00000000002ca000 Win32Thread: ffffaf0431c83df0 RUNNING on processor 0
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 ffffc18dfc3e77a0
Owning Process            ffffaf042f00c580       Image:         myProc.exe
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
Wait Start TickCount      77352          Ticks: 1 (0:00:00:00.015)
Context Switch Count      211            IdealProcessor: 1             
UserTime                  00:00:00.015
KernelTime                00:00:00.421
Win32 Start Address 0x0000000000020000
Stack Init ffffd708131a7c10 Current ffffd708131a6b40
Base ffffd708131a8000 Limit ffffd708131a1000 Call 0000000000000000
Priority 9 BasePriority 8 PriorityDecrement 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00000000`00a1fd8c 00020000`f40a8522 : cccccccc`00020000 00a1fe04`cccccccc 00a1fdbc`00a1fe04 00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc : MyDll!Init+0x280 [c:\projects\develop\source\MyDll.cpp @ 32] 
00000000`00a1fd94 cccccccc`00020000 : 00a1fe04`cccccccc 00a1fdbc`00a1fe04 00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc cccccccc`00a1fdc8 : 0x00020000`f40a8522
00000000`00a1fd9c 00a1fe04`cccccccc : 00a1fdbc`00a1fe04 00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc cccccccc`00a1fdc8 00a1fe5c`00000000 : 0xcccccccc`00020000
00000000`00a1fda4 00a1fdbc`00a1fe04 : 00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc cccccccc`00a1fdc8 00a1fe5c`00000000 00000000`00824890 : 0x00a1fe04`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fdac 00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc : cccccccc`00a1fdc8 00a1fe5c`00000000 00000000`00824890 008248e4`00000000 : 0x00a1fdbc`00a1fe04
00000000`00a1fdb4 cccccccc`00a1fdc8 : 00a1fe5c`00000000 00000000`00824890 008248e4`00000000 00a1fec4`00a1fe70 : 0x00a1fdc8`00a1fdbc
00000000`00a1fdbc 00a1fe5c`00000000 : 00000000`00824890 008248e4`00000000 00a1fec4`00a1fe70 cccccccc`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`00a1fdc8
00000000`00a1fdc4 00000000`00824890 : 008248e4`00000000 00a1fec4`00a1fe70 cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc : 0x00a1fe5c`00000000
00000000`00a1fdcc 008248e4`00000000 : 00a1fec4`00a1fe70 cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc : 0x824890
00000000`00a1fdd4 00a1fec4`00a1fe70 : cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc : 0x008248e4`00000000
00000000`00a1fddc cccccccc`cccccccc : cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc : 0x00a1fec4`00a1fe70
00000000`00a1fde4 cccccccc`cccccccc : cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc 00820000`00000000 : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fdec cccccccc`cccccccc : cccccccc`cccccccc cccccccc`cccccccc 00820000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fdf4 cccccccc`cccccccc : cccccccc`cccccccc 00820000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fdfc cccccccc`cccccccc : 00820000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fe04 00820000`00000000 : cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 00830000`00000000 : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fe0c cccccccc`cccccccc : 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 00830000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc : 0x00820000`00000000
00000000`00a1fe14 00000000`cccccccc : cccccccc`00000007 00830000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fe1c cccccccc`00000007 : 00830000`00000000 cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 : 0xcccccccc
00000000`00a1fe24 00830000`00000000 : cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 00000000`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`00000007
00000000`00a1fe2c cccccccc`cccccccc : 00000000`cccccccc cccccccc`00000007 00000000`cccccccc 008248e4`00a1fe5c : 0x00830000`00000000
00000000`00a1fe34 00000000`cccccccc : cccccccc`00000007 00000000`cccccccc 008248e4`00a1fe5c cccccccc`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
00000000`00a1fe3c cccccccc`00000007 : 00000000`cccccccc 008248e4`00a1fe5c cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`00000000 : 0xcccccccc
00000000`00a1fe44 00000000`cccccccc : 008248e4`00a1fe5c cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`00000000 cccccccc`008248e4 : 0xcccccccc`00000007
00000000`00a1fe4c 008248e4`00a1fe5c : cccccccc`cccccccc 00000000`00000000 cccccccc`008248e4 00000000`00a1fecc : 0xcccccccc
00000000`00a1fe54 cccccccc`cccccccc : 00000000`00000000 cccccccc`008248e4 00000000`00a1fecc cccccccc`00820000 : 0x008248e4`00a1fe5c
00000000`00a1fe5c 00000000`00000000 : cccccccc`008248e4 00000000`00a1fecc cccccccc`00820000 cccccccc`cccccccc : 0xcccccccc`cccccccc
```

As expected, the thread call-stack is not organized properly since the process runs on 32bit emulator, and it's dumped in 64bit mode.

However, when switching to wow64 mode (`!wow64exts.sw`), thread couldn't be dumped as all

```
32.0: kd:x86> !thread
3002e080: Unable to get thread contents
```

The same behavior occur in `!process` command.

```
32.0: kd:x86> !process
Searching for Process with Cid == 2f00c580
2e4739d0: Unable to read list
Cannot resolve nt!_EPROCESS object type
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: switching to x86 mode using `!wow64exts.sw` is like issuing the `.effmach x86` command, you're stuck with 32-bit addresses (and as your host is 64-bit, that can't work). Stay in host mode (x64) if you want to issue commands with 64-bit pointers. If you want the x86 stack, just switch the context to the thread with `.thread /w <ethread>` and then `k`.

Comment: Which version of WinDbg are you using? 32 bit or 64 bit? `Cannot resolve _EPROCESS` sounds like missing symbols. IMHO you should use the 32 bit version of WinDbg and ideally take a 32 bit crash dump, except you explicitly want to debug Wow64 issues.